# Reverse animation direction when hitting the side of the screen

Tags: c++, sfml

I am creating a space invaders game for my university assignment. I am breaking the parts down on paper, I thought a good place to start would be to move the sprites across the screen. The issue I have at the moment is this, when the sprite his the right hand side of the screen it would just carry on moving, so I added this code:

```
    if (invadersSprite.getPosition().x > 650)           
    {
        std::cout << "WIDTH_END" << std::endl;
    }
```

I basically used this for debugging for future reference. The output popped up into the console so I knew I was onto something. So, I started moving on from the output to actually moving the sprites back to the left hand side of the screen. I am now having more issues then expected.

I declared some ints for up, left, right and down just for easability when it comes to reading the code.

```
int spriteWalkSpeed = 50;
int up=-spriteWalkSpeed, down=spriteWalkSpeed, left=-spriteWalkSpeed, right=spriteWalkSpeed;
```

I've tried using the SFML move commands and also setPosition, but none of them really work as I thought they should.

**move:**

The issue I have had with this one is it basically stops in the middle of the screen. It still animates the leg movement and such, but it doesn't move left or right.

```
    if (invadersSprite.getPosition().x > 650)           
    {
        invadersSprite.move(left, 00);
    }
```

**setPosition:**

This is a little closer to what I am after, but still no cigar. The movement pauses for around a second and then pops up at the left hand side of the screen. What I need is to move back down the screen.

```
    if (invadersSprite.getPosition().x > 650)           
    {
        invadersSprite.setPosition(left, 00);
    }
```

I haven't been using SFML for very long so I am a little puzzled by this.

**EDIT**

At the moment the sprite is moving to the right of the screen, as needed:

```
if(spriteTimer>delay)
            {
                invadersSprite.setTextureRect(area);
                ++count;
                invadersSprite.move(right,0);
                if(count==SPRITECOLS) //WE HAVE MOVED OFF THE RIGHT OF THE IMAGE
                {
                    area.left=0;            //reset texture rect at left

                    count=0;                //reset count
                }
                else
                {
                    area.left+=spaceWidth; //move texture rect right

                }


                spriteTimer=0; //we have made one move in the sprite tile - start timing for the next move
            }
```

Comment: I would create `left, right` etc. as SFML vectors instead of integers.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I shall do some research on this as I haven't used vectors before.

Comment: `getPosition().x` <- `getPosition` returns a vector (`sf::Vector2`?), and you are accessing it's `x` component

Comment: I tried adding a new vector:
Vector.new(x, y, z = 0.0); but it kept coming up with this error "this declaration has no storage or type specifier"

Comment: How about reading the docs before writing anything?

Comment: I was reading the docs on this page: http://www.wg2140.com/users/trickster/doc/classes/SFML/Vector.html

Comment: That doesn't look like C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic will only move the sprite left once if the x-coord is greater than 650 - but that's not exactly what you want. What you want is for the sprite to continuously move left after reaching the edge.

To do this you'll need to keep track of a current velocity for your sprite. For example, when your sprite starts, it will be moving right:

`xVelocity = right;`

Then you can have 2 conditions that will switch direction (when hitting edges of screen):

```
if (invaderSprite.getPosition().x >= screenWidth) {
    // hit the right side of screen
    xVelocity = left;
} else if (invaderSprite.getPosition().x <= 0) {
    // hit the left side of screen
    xVelocity = right;
}
```

Now, on ever game tick, you simply move your sprite according to its current velocity:

`invaderSprite.move(xVelocity, yVelocity);`

There are some other things that will need to be fixed, like taking the width of the sprite into consideration, changing the y velocity, etc., but this is the main idea.

Comment: Sorry I think I have missed off something valuable. At the moment the sprite is moving all the way to the right. I'll edit original post

Comment: Yes, and you should replace that `invadersSprite.move(right,0);` with moving according to the sprites current velocity. You don't always want to move to the right, you only want to move to the right until you hit the right wall, then you want to move left until you hit the left wall, and so on, correct?